# Bootstrap validator custom function present only after destroy. Is this behavior expected?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I was working with [bootstrap-validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/) and noticed a strange behaviour of the plugin.

Made this test to confirm what I was suspecting:

```
  QUnit.test('call custom validator', function (assert) {

      var form = '<form>'
  + '<div class="form-group has-error">'
  + '<input type="text" value="example" data-validation1 data-validation2>'
  + '<input type="text" value="mobilephone" data-requiredone="phone">'
  + '<div class="help-block with-errors">Fill at least one</div>'
  + '</div>'
  + '</form>'

      var $form = $(form)
        .appendTo('#qunit-fixture')
        .validator()

      var options1 = {
          custom: {
              validation1: function (element) { }
          }
      }

      var options2 = {
          custom: {
              validation2: function (element) { }
          }
      };

      var form = $('form').validator(options1)

      var validator = $(form).data("bs.validator")

      assert.ok(validator.options.custom.validation1 && validator.options.custom.validation1.toString() == options1.custom.validation1.toString(), 'validator.options.custom contains validation1')

      $('form').validator('destroy')

      $('form').validator(options2)

      validator = $("form").data("bs.validator")

      assert.ok(validator.options.custom.validation2 && validator.options.custom.validation2.toString() == options2.custom.validation2.toString(), 'validator.options.custom contains validation2')
  })
```

The [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlE9o.jpg) are the first assert passes the second does not.

And also find out that 'destroy' is kinda a workaround, what bugs me even more.

I also posted this question at [github](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/480) of the project.

Can please someone tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response from the creator off the plugin :

> You already initialized the plugin without the custom validator with
>
> ```
>   var $form = $(form)
>     .appendTo('#qunit-fixture')
>     .validator()
> ```
>
> The plugin doesn't reinitialize itself with new options if you call .validator() again. This might change in the future.

the answer is YES, is the expected behavior.